# How to supervise a process and schedule a periodic restart?

Tags: process

I run a process that sometime crash and sometime freeze.  I used supervise to have it automatically restart when it crash.  However, if it freeze, it stay frozen until I am back in front of the computer.  I would like a tool that would restart it when it crash, but can also be configure to do periodic kill and restart, so if it freeze, it won't stay frozen more that a given period of time.

Which tool would who suggest?

Thanks

Comment: The process is a java process.  pkill java won't work, since they are other java process I don't wish to kill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using supervise from [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) with a crontab :

First, I start with

```
supervise /fullpath
```

and I use this crontab :

```
0 23 * * * svc -d /fullpath
2 23 * * * svc -k /fullpath
5 23 * * * svc -u /fullpath
```

Where fullpath is the directory containing the file called run which start my process.  The tricky part is the file called should end with :

```
exec java ...
```

Normally, I start the application with a script, but if I put that script in the file called run, when svc is executed, it send the signal to the script and the java process continue to run.  I created a copy of the script and modified it to make it output the call to java with all parameter, and copied this in the file called run.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cron to do this if you want...

```
sudo crontab -e

* /5 * * * pkill -9 <your process name here> ; <your process name here>
```

Would kill and restart it every 5 hours.
More examples... [Cron examples](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Comment: It would, but it won't supervise it.  I want a tool that boot supervise it and restart it.

Comment: pkill java might kill the wrong process.